# Does twitter_bootstrap_form_for work with f.select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to wrap a rails f.select dropdown tag in a twitter bootstrap dropdown style then submit to the selection to the database when a submit button is pushed?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but I'm just trying to figure this question out myself. It appears from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257130/twitter-bootstrapping-a-locale-selector-drop-down-in-rails-3/) that you can't style form select using bootstrap dropdown styling. The suggestion is to lose the form.

Answer (score 0):

As answered in [Twitter Bootstrapping a locale selector drop-down in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257130/twitter-bootstrapping-a-locale-selector-drop-down-in-rails-3/) the native Bootstrap dropdown does not support `<select>` based markup. So most of the time adapting to an `<ul><li>` based markup will be easier and more consistent.

If that's not possible, there could be other solutions like relating a hidden `<select>` with a visible `.dropdown` via Javascript.