# Twitter Bootstrapping a locale selector drop-down in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, drop-down-menu, internationalization, twitter-bootstrap

I have a non-Bootstrapped locale selector in my otherwise generally Bootstrapped Rails 3 app that I want to Bootstrap-ify.  I'm a bit stumped as to how to make an (I assume) unordered list in a form in a dropdown menu.

#### **TL;DR** Go to Edit 3 at the bottom of this question for the completed solution.

The current code is implemented in the following way:

**app/views/layouts/_header.html.haml**

```
%header.navbar.navbar-fixed-top
  .navbar-inner
    .container
      # ...
      %nav
        %ul.nav.pull-right
          # ...
          %li= render 'layouts/locale_selector',
                       controller: controller, 
                       action: action
          # (controller, action params passed in from application.html.haml)
```

**app/views/layouts/_locale_selector.html.haml**

```
= form_tag({ controller: controller,
             action: action },
             method: 'get',
             class: 'locale') do
  = select_tag 'set_locale',
               options_for_select(locale_languages, I18n.locale)
  = hidden_field_tag 'page', params[:page] if params[:page]
  = submit_tag 'submit'
```

**app/helpers/application_helper.rb**

```
module ApplicationHelper
  # ...
  def locale_languages
    [
      [t('locale_selector.en'), 'en'],
      [t('locale_selector.it'), 'it'],
      [t('locale_selector.ja'), 'ja']
    ]
  end
end
```

**app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss**

```
# ...
.locale {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  margin: -0.25em;
  #set_locale {
    width: 85px;
    height: 36px;
    color: $grayLight;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    text-align: center;
    &:hover {
      color: $white;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
  }
}
```

**app/assets/javascripts/application.js.coffee**

```
$ ->
  $(".locale input").hide()
  $("#set_locale").change ->
    $(this).closest("form").submit()
```

By reading through [the Bootstrap component documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html) I've changed **header.html.haml** to the code below to get the drop-down list displaying how I want, but it's getting the content in the `select_tag`, `options_for_select` etc displaying/working correctly that I'm not sure about:

**app/views/layouts/_header.html.haml**

```
# ...
%li#fat-menu.dropdown
  %a.dropdown-toggle{"data-toggle" => "dropdown", href: "#"}
    = t('.language')
    %b.caret
  .dropdown-menu
    = render 'layouts/locale_selector',
              controller: controller,
              action: action
```

I've tried to find info in [the Bootstrap documentation on forms](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms) and by searching around StackOverflow and Google, but to no avail.  I bet I'm missing something simple and/or trivial, but could any Bootstrap experts help me out?

#### Edit

Changed 2 files to get the drop-down looking nice, but it still doesn't submit yet...

**app/helpers/application_helper.rb**

```
module ApplicationHelper
  # ...
  def locale_languages
    [
      { label: t('locale_selector.en'), locale: 'en' },
      { label: t('locale_selector.it'), locale: 'it' },
      { label: t('locale_selector.ja'), locale: 'ja' }
    ]
  end
end
```

**app/views/layouts/_locale_selector.html.haml**

```
= form_tag({ controller: controller,
             action: action },
             method: 'get',
             class: 'locale') do
  - locale_languages.each do |language|
    %li= link_to language[:label], '#', value: language[:locale]
  = hidden_field_tag 'page', params[:page] if params[:page]
  = submit_tag 'submit'
```

#### Edit 2

**app/assets/javascripts/application.js.coffee**

```
$ ->
  $(".locale input").hide()
  $(".locale").click ->
    $(this).closest("form").submit()
```

Now it submits, but all my original backend handling of the `params[:set_locale]` in my `ApplicationController` is broken (won't put the code here, but for the curious [here it is](https://github.com/paulfioravanti/sample_app/blob/master/app/controllers/application_controller.rb)), so the locale doesn't change.  Need to try and get this to pass back a `params[:set_locale]` value...

### Edit 3: The Completed Solution

Got rid of the form entirely, which I should have done in the first place as pointed out by @simbirsk and @quick_brown_fox.  Many thanks, guys.  Here is the final code:

**app/views/layouts/_header.html.haml**

```
%header.navbar.navbar-fixed-top
  .navbar-inner
    .container
      # ...
      %nav
        %ul.nav.pull-right
          # ...
          %li= render 'layouts/locale_selector',
                       controller: controller, 
                       action: action
          # (controller, action params passed in from application.html.haml)
```

**app/views/layouts/_locale_selector.html.haml**

```
%li#fat-menu.dropdown
  %a.dropdown-toggle{"data-toggle" => "dropdown", href: "#"}
    = t('.language')
    %b.caret
  %ul.dropdown-menu
    - locale_languages.each do |language|
      %li
        = link_to language[:label],
                  controller: controller,
                  action: action,
                  set_locale: language[:locale],
                  page: params[:page]
```

**app/helpers/application_helper.rb**

```
module ApplicationHelper
  # ...
  def locale_languages
    [
      { label: t('locale_selector.en'), locale: 'en' },
      { label: t('locale_selector.it'), locale: 'it' },
      { label: t('locale_selector.ja'), locale: 'ja' }
    ]
  end
end
```

Code mentioned above in **app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss** and **app/assets/javascripts/application.js.coffee** was completely removed as it became superfluous.

**Update**: 
This seems to be getting a lot of views, so:

- You can find the full implementation of the locale drop-down, including the code in the controller [here](https://github.com/paulfioravanti/sample_app) in the app I made for Michael Hartl's [Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<select>` solution looks great, but unfortunatelly that's not Bootstrap native.
As said in documents, markup for a navbar dropdown is as follows:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dLabel" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" href="/page.html">
        Language
        <b class="caret"></b>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
        <li><a href="#">English</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portuguese</a></li>
        ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

So, if you want to stay "Bootstraped", adapt your code and generate (dinamically, if you wish) a collection of `<li>` containing links to each language. You can post any data you need using `<%= link_to %>`

Comment: +1 for the `link_to` advice.  Seems so obvious now.  I'm not quite where I want to be just yet...still need to get the form to submit.  I'll add the new code to an edit to the question.

Comment: For some reason I was blind to your code (and the documentation) not having a form in it.  I get it now, finally.  Your method was how I got to my solution, so I accept your answer.  I'll put my full code in an edit to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way to style a `<select>` element as a dropdown via Bootstrap.
Instead of using a form, how about using links in an unordered list and maybe changing your controller a little bit?

Or – if that's no solution, you probably will have to use some JavaScript magic or create some kind of POST link (I'm not so much into Rails right now to remember exactly how you do that, but you can, right?)

(Not sure if I got your question right …)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  You're right: there is some javascript magic involved that I forgot to post, so I added it to the question.  I know there is a way to style `select`s in Bootstrap as per [the documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms), and I got that working, but I'm aiming for the nice-looking drop-down.  I don't think I can use a `post` link because my form itself submits using `get` to change a page to another language.

Comment: Like @simbirsk I'd go with a `link_to` solution. Just pass the parameter with the link url, use the dropdown with an `ul` like in the Bootstrap docs and you're done.

Of course you can also use a form, but I can't see a benefit in it. On the contray: it makes it makes things more complicated IMHO.

Comment: +1 for your advice.  Thank you for writing "Of course you can also use a form, but I can't see a benefit in it".  This was the jolt needed for me to realize I'd ignored @simbirsk's advice and the documentation by keeping the `form` in.  It's coming out.